# Next JS 13 progress bar is not working at all

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I'm using the new Next JS 13 `app` dir. but i'm facing an issue of that when page loads the progress bar at the top is not working.

in the old next JS 12 there is a package to simplify this. its called `nprogress` and `nextNprogress` but when it comes to app dir it doesn't work. how cam i make this work?

`layout.jsx`

```
import Router from 'next/router';
import NProgress from 'nprogress'; //nprogress module
import 'nprogress/nprogress.css'; //styles of nprogress

Router.events.on('routeChangeStart', () => NProgress.start()); 
Router.events.on('routeChangeComplete', () => NProgress.done()); 
Router.events.on('routeChangeError', () => NProgress.done());

function RootLayout({ children }) {
 
  return (
    <html>
      <head />
      <body className="max-w-7xl mx-auto">
        {/* <NextNProgress /> */}
        <ChakraProvider>{children}</ChakraProvider>
      </body>
    </html>
  );
}
export default wrapper.withRedux(RootLayout);
```

Answer (score 1):

Well clearly neither `nprogress` nor `nextNprogress` are ready for the new `app` structure, so you have to wait until they get updated to support NextJS 13+ and only then migrate to the new structure.

Comment: so is there a manual way?. like how can i access the routing loading value?. if i can convert the loading state to a percent i can make my own progressbar

Comment: `app` structure has a [separate file](https://beta.nextjs.org/docs/routing/loading-ui) for loading state.

Comment: yes but i wanted to display the loading on top. the `loading.js` file will create a new screen.

Comment: Loading on top for what exactly? It is only useful for page transitions, you don't need to show it for every async action within the page. I'd suggest you to drop the "global loading bar" idea and go along with whatever nextjs expects you to do, which is per-page loading screens. Otherwise you'll end up in a situation where you have to synchronize the state of your client app with async server response streams, which isn't fun to do just for a progress bar.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use next13-progressbar that supports appdir in nextjs. https://www.npmjs.com/package/next13-progressbar

Answer (score -2):

There are hacky ways using useEffect to get it working [check it here](https://github.com/apal21/nextjs-progressbar/issues/86#issuecomment-1597912679) My advice is to use the library  [nextjs-toploader](https://github.com/TheSGJ/nextjs-toploader) it uses [nprogress](https://github.com/rstacruz/nprogress) under the hood

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34584914)